# how to reference a child element on a cloned element

Tags: javascript, path, element

I am running some tests on a DOM element,
the result of the tests is one of the element descendants.
for example:

```
<div id="myelement" class="some-class">
  <div class="some-child-class"></div>
  <div class="some-other-child-class">
    <div class="grandchild-class"></div>
    <div class="another-grandchild"></div>*
  </div>
</div>
```

let's assume that:

```
test(document.getElementById('myelement'));
```

will return the Element marked with asterisk

Now my problem is:
The test procedure is heavy and resource consuming.
I don't want to run it when i don't have to.
And sometimes, I clone an element that has already been tested (meaning - i KNOW the result of the test), but since I am getting an object reference as a result I can't use it to access the relevant child on the cloned element.

Is there any efficient way of somehow "save" the relative path from a parent Element to a specific descendant DOM element and then "apply" it on another element?

Comment: Why not just select the element rather than traversing though the DOM?

Comment: Have you tried re-using a selector? The selector is just a string ,i,e: 'input .withclass' and you should be able to re-use this on any element set.

Comment: Maybe somehow mark already tested elements? Using dataset for example.

Comment: Not knowing what you are testing, just curios, are you unit or integration testing? I would be concerned if any of my JavaScript unit tests are `heavy and resource consuming` as that is either a sign of bad design in the code under test or bad testing setup (not mocking things that should be mocked etc..) and might be something to address directly?

Comment: @Fran: "heavy and resource consuming" is a relative term :-) those tests are executed in run-time. just a few ms each. but it adds up... and i am trying to be as performant as possible.

Comment: @YairLevy you could add a class or any other property to the already tested elements, so before you test them again check if they have that class/property.

Comment: @Deus777  as for marking the tested elements... it does not help, because i still need to access a specific node under the cloned element. I am looking for a way to somehow "mark the path" to a deep nested node, and use this path to access a different node (nested in the cloned element)

Comment: @YairLevy Fair enough :) If thousands of tests run, each taking a few ms but you find that too slow, maybe you can run the tests in parallel (if you are not already) ? In general applying a custom "solution" that might cause issues later when something that should be tested ends up not being tested might jeopardize 100% reliability on the tests?

Answer (score 0):

So you could assign unique ids to each element and cache the test results in an Object at the Elements id. However, i dont know if this is useful. An example implementation:

```
var test=function(el){
  return this[el.id] || (this[el.id]=advancedtesting(el));
}.bind({});
```

So you could do:

```
test(document.getElementById('myelement'));//caches
test(document.getElementById('myelement'));//returns the cached
```

Answer (score -1):

You could use jQuery for that.

The selectors they use can take the form of 'nth-child' or 'nth-of-type' (see documentation [here](https://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/)).

What is does is that targets child element from the position they have relative from where you start from. 
In your case if you want to start from your first element and go down to the starred one you can do:

```
$('#myelement').find('div:nth-child(2) > div:nth-child(2)')
```

What this does is that it takes #myelement as a base from which you will begin the search, and after that it goes down to the second child element that is a div, and again into this div's second child element.
You could reuse that selector with a different base.

Comment: Please don't recommend using jQuery when it has been neither tagged nor referred to in the question itself.

Comment: OP seems to want to improve speed on tests running only a few ms, introducing another library probably wouldn't help speeding the tests up.

Comment: Sorry maybe OP wants pure javascript, for any kind of reason. I'm not sure the performance would be so much worse though.